# Using Firebase Google Auth to Also Get Access to Users Gmail

Tags: swift, firebase, gmail-api

I am trying to create an IOS app with Firebase that also has access to the user's Gmail Account.

I already have the Firebase Google Sign-In Method implemented with **no issues**, *but am wondering how I can retrieve the Auth token for the User's Gmail Account* so I can use the Gmail API to load their emails in the app.

**Here is my signup code:**

```
func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
          present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                 withError error: Error!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        print("|*| Name: \(fullName), Email: \(email)")
    } else {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can request access to their email when presenting the sign-in screen from Google?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can succeed with the log-in part if OAuth is used. But, take note that making calls to [Gmail API methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) will require you to use [Gmail specific scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes).

Check the guide [Using Google APIs with Firebase Auth and Firebase UI on the Web](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-google-apis-with-firebase-auth-and-firebase-ui-on-the-web-46e6189cf571) with regard to your implementation.

Comment: Thanks, @nogui I was able to get Gmail to work with my Firebase Auth. It now asks for me to give permission to my app to use Gmail. Do you know how one might get the token for Gmail? I am using the Postal Swift Library to work  with email and that is required.